# Хранение значений переменных после закрытия программы и загрузка их при открытии?

Tags: ios, objective-c, хранение-данных

Например, как можно реализовать хранение имени профиля и пароля, чтобы не надо было заново ничего вводить при повторном запуске программы?

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен, добавьте больше информации...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более качественное решение будет использование CoreData https://habrahabr.ru/post/191472/
Более простое через `NSUserDefaults`

Создать 2 property

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * password;`

Запись:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.email forKey:@"email"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Чтение:

`self.email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email"];
self.password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];`

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения данных между запуском приложения в iOS существует множество способов, зависит от тредбований:

1. Класс синглетон `NSUserDefaults` хранение данных в виде ключ-значение. Удобен для простых типов и структур данных. Не безопасен, т.к. все данных хранятся в директории проекта, без шифрования.
2. Хранение объектной модели данных с кодированием и декодированием в `NSKeyedArchiver / NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Классы модели данных должны соответствовать протоколу `NSCoding`. Простой в использовании, каждое поле класса будет храниться по соответствующему ключу.  Ниже представлен пример хранения данных единственного объекта класса AppUser:

> ```
> interface AppUser : NSObject
> @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *email, *password, *aToken;
> @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *organisations;
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL isLogin;
> +(AppUser *) sharedUser;
> -(BOOL) saveAppUsersData;
> -(void) logout;
> @end
> ```
>
> #define
>   archivePath(name)[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
>   NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingString:[[@"/"
>   stringByAppendingString:(name)] stringByAppendingString:@".archive"]]
>
> ```
> @implementation AppUser
> @synthesize password, email, isLogin, isAdmin, name, organisations, aToken;
>
> static AppUser *mSharedUser;
>
> +(AppUser *) sharedUser
> {
>     @synchronized(self) {
>         if (!mSharedUser) {
>             mSharedUser = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath(@"AppUser")];
>             if (!mSharedUser)
>                 mSharedUser = [[self alloc] init];
>         }
>         return mSharedUser;
>     }
> }
>
> -(id) init
> {
>     self = [super init];
>     if (self) {
>         isLogin = NO;
>         organisations = [NSMutableArray new];
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
> - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
> {
>     [aCoder encodeObject:email forKey:@"email"];
>     [aCoder encodeObject:password forKey:@"password"];
>     [aCoder encodeBool:isLogin forKey:@"isLogin"];
>     [aCoder encodeObject:aToken forKey:@"aToken"];
>     [aCoder encodeObject:organisations forKey:@"organisations"];
> }
>
> - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
> {
>     self = [super init];
>     if (self) {
>         email = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
>         password = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
>         isLogin = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isLogin"];
>         organisations = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"organisations"];
>         aToken = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"aToken"];
>         if (!organisations)
>             organisations = [NSMutableArray new];
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
> -(BOOL) saveAppUsersData
> {
>     return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[AppUser sharedUser] toFile:archivePath(@"AppUser")];
> }
>
> -(void) logout
> {
>     NSError *error;
>     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:archivePath(@"AppUser") error:&error];
>     mSharedUser = [[AppUser alloc] init];
> }
> ```

3. База данный SQLLite, CoreData, Realm. Основной способ для создания хранилища, модели данных и запросов для их выборки. Наиболее быстрый и надежный способ. Поддержка многопоточности.

> Realm -  кросс-платформенные и могут совместно использоваться iOS и
>   Android. Независимо от того, Вы работаете с Java, Objective-C, или
>   Swift, вы будете использовать высокоуровневые модели. https://realm.io